# Import vector graphics from PDF to GIMP

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, vector-graphics, gimp, inkscape

I need to extract vector graphics from a PDF image and import them into GIMP, either as paths or as high-resolution raster images. Specifically, I need to get contour lines from USGS topographical maps and overlay them on satellite images. Any suggestions?

So far I have tried:

--Using GIMP's native PDF importing function to import them as raster images. Problem: To do so at high resolution crashes my computer. Possible solution would be to import only a selected area of a PDF, but as far as I can tell this is not possible.

--Using ImageMagick to convert the PDF to a raster image. Problem: Used with the "-scale" parameter, "convert" appears to rasterize the PDF and then upscale it, leading to a choppy image.

--Using InkScape to extract the necessary vector elements from the PDF. Problem: InkScape freezes when I try to open a moderately large (25 Mb) PDF.

Any other ideas?

Many thanks,
treacl

Comment: Adding -density 300 (or higher) before loading your PDF with ImageMagick should improve the quality.

Answer (score 0):

The option you didn't mention above is to try to use the ghostscript program directly to render your output - ghostscript is used internally by GIMP to import PDF files, so you likely have it installed already.

There are tens of command switches to pass ghostscript for it to render a file into another format - the switches you need to pass are for determining the output size, resolution and which page to print. I didn't find any switch to select a portion of the page to be rendered - so, if your document is a single page, it is possible the generated file will still be to big for GIMP - but you will likely be able to crop it with ImageMagick, at least.

I guess the relevant command line for you would be something along:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=page.png -dFirstPage=<pagenumber> -dLastPage=<pagenumber> -r<dpiresolution>  -f<filename.pdf>
```

If the resulting image is still too large to be generated or operated upon, you can try changing the output format to use a smaller color depth (this one is 3 bytes per pixel: png16m) .  It should be possible to pass postscript commands to transform the device, so that the area of interest is scaled up to your page size (and the remaining parts are cropped out of the rendering) - that would be the definitive fix for you - but of the top of my head, I don't know how to do that with ghostscript.

Alternatively, you can try passing ImageMagick the `-density` parameter as suggested in the comments.